# Setting up www and naked redirects in AWS Route53 with multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname, amazon-route53

I'm trying to set up a top-level hosted zone in AWS Route53 in a master account which acts as a proxy for 3 other (production, staging, development) accounts. The aim of the final set up is as follows:

1. www.foo.com -> production account
2. foo.com -> re-directs to www.foo.com
3. stage.foo.com -> staging account
4. dev.foo.com -> development account

To clarify, there are 4 accounts:

- Master
- Production
- Staging
- Development

**Master Account**

So far, 3 and 4 are working ok. The root account has the following:

Hosted Zone (foo.com)
- foo.com NS (4 name servers) - default
- foo.com SOA - default

Record Sets I've added:

- dev.foo.com NS (added 4 name servers of *dev* account NS default record)
- stage.foo.com NS (added 4 name servers of *stage* account NS default record)

**Staging Account**

Hosted Zone (stage.foo.com)

- stage.foo.com NS (4 name servers) - default
- stage.foo.com SOA - default

Record Sets I've added:

- stage.foo.com A Record (ALIAS) -> AWS ELB

**Development Account**

Hosted Zone (dev.foo.com) - **Same as Stage**

- dev.foo.com NS (4 name servers) - default
- dev.foo.com SOA - default

Record Sets I've added:

- dev.foo.com A Record (ALIAS) -> AWS ELB

The problem I'm facing is how to set up the www. and naked url for the production account.

If I repeat the same steps as *stage* and *dev*, by creating and delegating the Name Servers of www.foo.com to the production account with a hosted zone of www.foo.com - what can I do about handling the naked url *foo.com*.

Should this be handled in the Master account or Production account?

Another idea is to have nothing in the Master account, and handle everything in the production account. This would have the naked A Alias record pointing to the www A Alias record, which in turn points to the AWS ELB, and then hand off the Name Servers for staging and dev to their own accounts.

Another twist would be to keep it as it is mentioned above but have the naked A Alias record pointing to the www A IP address of the Production AWS ELB.

Would either of these be a better approach or is it possible to handle it all in the Master account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `example.com` hosted zone in the production account, and create all the production records in there.

Delegate `stage` and `dev` to their respective hosted zones, as you have done, in order to maintain structural separation and help prevent inadvertent production changes.  Remember that sometimes these queries will cause 2 requests -- one hitting the global domain to find the delegation, and another to find the actual record from the subdomain.  Not a big deal, since these should have relatively low volume.

But, which "account" (referring, I assume, to consolidated billing accounts) you put the hosted zones in will be a matter of convenience.  Resources can be accessed across account boundaries with correct configuration, but not crossing account boundaries is always easier, with less to configure.  There's no technical reason why they couldn't all go in the master account.  They *could* all go in the same hosted zone for that matter -- hostname 'foo.dev' in the 'example.com' hosted zone will be used to resolve 'foo.dev.example.com' if you don't do the delegation -- but separation is good.

Comment: Hi Michael - to clarify, for stage & dev (per para. 2) are you saying to keep these in the global/master account or should I move the entries to the production account and delegate from there. 

The issue I'm having in the global account is I created a hosted zone for foo.com and can't delegate foo.com on to production as it clashes with the existing Name Servers in the global account.

Comment: There's not really a correct answer, but, yes, you'll need to put it in only one or the other.  My instinct says production.